# Change the cronjob dynamically using Form

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, job-scheduling

I am using bull npm module to schedule the jobs in nodejs. 
For the repeated jobs, I would like to pass the value to cron using form and change it dynamically.

For e.g. For every monday-friday at 10:10, it repeats and it is static.

```
cron: '10 10 * * mon-fri'
```

But I would like to change the cron's value dynamically, time as well as day from UI using form.
What would be the best way to start.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You create an API that you access from a interface. For example Express or HAPI.js is good examples of many of the available web-application frameworks for node.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a one crone job for one hour so after one hour we need to increment the count so we know that how much time is spent.

---

ex:

1> if i would like to call a function after 3 hours i will store 3 hours value in database lets say i store that value in local_value column in table.

2> set crone job to every hour so after one hour when crone hit i increment one flag and store that value in db lets say i store that data in server_value column in table.

3> now every hour when crone hit i compare the both column value serve_value and local_value if both values are same then that means 3 hours spent and execute the code.

Comment: Please take the time to provide an understandable answer: edit your post and at least separate your sentences.